# Regressão Múltipla com Python - Resultados diferentes do Excel

Tags: python, microsoft-excel, regressão

Turma, estou rodando o modelo abaixo que me gera o resultado descrito na sequência.

```
import pandas
import statsmodels.api as sm

dados_tb1 = {'Disney': [0.08088, 0.04737, -0.04634, 0.16834, -0.09082],
        'MacDonalds':[-0.01309, 0.15958, 0.09966, 0.03125, 0.06206],
        'Schlumberger':[-0.08463, 0.02884, 0.00165, 0.09571, -0.05723],
        'Haliburton':[-0.13373, 0.03616, 0.07919, 0.09227, -0.13242]}
tb_1 = pd.DataFrame(data = dados_tb1)

Y = tb_1[['Disney']]
X = tb_1[['MacDonalds','Schlumberger', 'Haliburton' ]]
reg = sm.OLS(Y,X).fit()
reg.summary()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ocorre que esse resultado é diferente de quando faço pelo Excel, usando a análise de dados, (que é o correto), como mostra a imagem seguinte:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Observem que os coeficientes (coef) e o R² (R-squared) são diferentes.

Onde estou errando, alguém consegue me auxiliar?

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: O modelo (OLS) é o mesmo para os dois?

Comment: Oi Paulo! Não sei ao certo como verificar ainda. Mas o resultado pelo Excel, que é obtido pela opção de Análise de dados (Dados -> Análise de dados -> Regressão), é o correto.

Comment: Vi que pelo R com o código abaixo tenho o resultado esperado tbm.

`Disney <- c(0.08088, 0.04737, -0.04634, 0.16834, -0.09082)
MacDonalds <- c(-0.01309, 0.15958, 0.09966, 0.03125, 0.06206)
Schlumberger<-c(-0.08463, 0.02884, 0.00165, 0.09571, -0.05723)
Haliburton<-c(-0.13373, 0.03616, 0.07919, 0.09227, -0.13242)

tb_1 <- data.frame(Disney = Disney, MacDonalds=MacDonalds, 
                   Schlumberger=Schlumberger, Haliburton=Haliburton)

modelo <- lm(data=tb_1, Disney~.)

summary(modelo)`

Minha dúvida é como faço algo semelhante no Python?

Comment: Veja [este link](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/05/multiple-linear-regression-using-python-and-scikit-learn/) para regressão múltipla usando sklearn, talvez ajude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faltou apenas uma linha no seu código:

```py
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm

dados_tb1 = {'Disney': [0.08088, 0.04737, -0.04634, 0.16834, -0.09082],
        'MacDonalds':[-0.01309, 0.15958, 0.09966, 0.03125, 0.06206],
        'Schlumberger':[-0.08463, 0.02884, 0.00165, 0.09571, -0.05723],
        'Haliburton':[-0.13373, 0.03616, 0.07919, 0.09227, -0.13242]}
tb_1 = pd.DataFrame(data = dados_tb1)

Y = tb_1['Disney']        # <--- Não precisa ser tipo dataframe, pode ser série. Removi os colchetes extras.
X = tb_1[['MacDonalds','Schlumberger', 'Haliburton' ]]

X = sm.add_constant(X)    # <--- Faltou esta linha!

reg = sm.OLS(Y, X).fit()
reg.summary()
```

Nota: o método `add_constant()` adiciona uma coluna constante com o valor 1. Veja:

```
print(X)

   const  MacDonalds  Schlumberger  Haliburton
0    1.0    -0.01309      -0.08463    -0.13373
1    1.0     0.15958       0.02884     0.03616
2    1.0     0.09966       0.00165     0.07919
3    1.0     0.03125       0.09571     0.09227
4    1.0     0.06206      -0.05723    -0.13242
```

Resultado

```
<class 'statsmodels.iolib.summary.Summary'>
"""
                            OLS Regression Results
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                 Disney   R-squared:                       0.630
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                 -0.481
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                    0.5670
Date:                Sat, 23 Apr 2022   Prob (F-statistic):              0.724
Time:                        20:16:08   Log-Likelihood:                 7.3124
No. Observations:                   5   AIC:                            -6.625
Df Residuals:                       1   BIC:                            -8.187
Df Model:                           3
Covariance Type:            nonrobust
================================================================================
                   coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const            0.0938      0.098      0.956      0.514      -1.153       1.341
MacDonalds      -0.8812      1.105     -0.798      0.571     -14.915      13.153
Schlumberger     1.3151      1.988      0.662      0.628     -23.941      26.572
Haliburton      -0.1717      1.344     -0.128      0.919     -17.252      16.908
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                          nan   Durbin-Watson:                   1.057
Prob(Omnibus):                    nan   Jarque-Bera (JB):                0.514
Skew:                          -0.033   Prob(JB):                        0.773
Kurtosis:                       1.430   Cond. No.                         42.3
==============================================================================

Notes:
[1] Standard Errors assume that the covariance matrix of the errors is correctly specified.
"""
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Paulo.

Comment: Achando pertinente, marque a resposta como sendo a solução.